# Magento magmi Very slow at end of import

Tags: magmi, magento-1.9

Using magmi version v0.7.22_git Grouped Item processor on a dedicated server Magento 1.9.1 community  and I notice the last 80-100% of the import process goes very slow.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Working with large import files. Is this normal?

Comment: Actually it was at like 96.49% and it froze completely. Had to re import using the "Creat products, skip existing" feature

Comment: does it happen with CLI ? you are surely describing an UI flaw and UI is not designed for very large imports (due to PHP execution time limit). As i always say : Use UI for test drive & setup , use CLI for the real stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is. I am going to mywebsite.com/magmi/web/magmi.php

I switched back to v0.7.18 and it seemed to import smoothly (not slow down at the end) However I can not get catalog URL to index.

Comment: Okay I see you are talking about command line vs going to the web URL. I do not know how to run via command line. Only thing I usually run from command is indexing (which im trying to do not but its stuck) Can you tell me how to run these commands via CLI ?

Comment: all is described in the wiki. http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_command_line . moreover, the MAGMI Import URL UI plugin is a plugin showing different ways to automate a profile import , it has a dropdown with different entries and one of those is magmi cli, giving the command line to use to reproduce particular UI run setup.

Comment: So running command line does not use php and I should not run into this problem? Appreciate the help by the way. Been using magmi over 2 years now and never know about this stuff

Comment: running command line uses php (the command line is php magmi.cli.php) but php web execution model is different from php command line execution model. php cli is more suited for "long running" process where web execution model is mainly aimed at request execution.

Comment: I am trying to run the below command, I got it from the plugin but its not working. I get an error that says
-bash: magmi.cli.php: command not found The command is:magmi.cli.php -mode=update -profile=default     I have went to the magmi/cli folder

Comment: looks like I didnt add "php" before the command.

Comment: Yea it still gets stuck using cli. The particular import file that gets stuck has 32k lines of data and is 19MB

What would have to be done for me to import a file this large?

Comment: What I dont understand is why on the older magmi 7.18 it does not get stuck, but on the newer one it does.

Comment: could you share a link to the file so that i can investigate your problem ? send it to my email (dweeves link in magmi UI)

Comment: I've sent you an email as requested.

Comment: The subject of the email is "Told me to email you"